# odometry manually

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
i need to publish the odometry information over ROS with my own robot platform (SuperDroid platform) and i'm using Roboteq SDC21xx microcontroller.
the thing is that in this code
http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom
there are three variables that I have to provide which are
16 double vx = 0.1;
17 double vy = -0.1;
18 double vth = 0.1;
Now, my question is if i provided the values and computations of the variables manually.
which unit measures should I use?
inches/s ? radians?
how?

thank u

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205882/odometry-manually/) by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-25**:
yea and why do i have to provide the wheels size i dont get it

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-03-25**:
Why don't you follow the standard msg type for odom msgs? You can decide what units you want to send them in though as long as the node receiving the msg is aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**vx, vy, and vz are in meters/sec.  vth is in radians/second.**

**Take a look at this [site](http://www.geology.smu.edu/%7Edpa-www/robots/doc/odometry.txt).**

**One thing I would add about finding distance travelled and theta:**

To get distance, and therefore (x,y) position, you will have to know wheel circumference.  Encoder counts gives you how much the motor has turned, but if that motor is attached to a larger wheel, then the distance will obviously be greater.

**Example:**

If your robot was just riding on the motor shafts and your motor shafts were 0.04 m in circumference.  If you rotated your motor one full rotation, you will have traveled 0.04 m.

However, if your motor shaft was fixed to a wheel with a circumference of 0.25 m and you rotated your motor one full revolution, then you will have traveled 0.25m (ignoring friction and drag).

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-26**:
ok thank u

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-30**:
now that i got the distance traveled for x and y . i'll have to set vx to x and vy to y. correct?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-04-06**:
You will get vx and vy from the encoders as well.  The rate they are turning, giving you velocity in the x (usually set as forward) and y (usually set as robot's left) directions.

You usually command the motors to turn using /cmd_vel.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-04-06**:
I think for the purpose of the tutorial you mentioned, they just set vx and vy as an example to show the base_link moving in the odom frame.  You wouldn't actually put that when publishing your odometry message.

But I could be wrong.  I haven't had to do that from scratch yet.